# Qt Application exits with 0 when QMainWindow is minimized

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

This Qt project https://github.com/AmonRaNet/QGeoView exits when the main window is minimized ??!!?? Can someone give me an explanation please, I never saw that in my life with Qt. I'm using Windows 10 and I'm using the last version of Visual Studio 2019 C++ compiler. I have also used different Qt versions (the last version of Qt5 and the version provided by vcpkg).

I have already read the mainwindow code and there's nothing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From mainwindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::hideEvent(QHideEvent* /*event*/)
{
   QApplication::quit();
}
```

Comment: I hovered over the code and didn't pay attention to it.

Comment: things happen !